# front end add category to new post

Tags: categories, front-end

This is my issue, i hope to find the answer here.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="genres" class="col-sm-2 control-label">genres</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="genres" name="genres">
   </div>
</div>

// Genres value is : anime, action, adventure,

function post_creation() {
    if(isset($_POST['movie_nonce_field']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['movie_nonce_field'], 'movie_nonce')) {
        if(strlen(trim($_POST['title'])) < 1 || strlen(trim($_POST['overview'])) < 1) {
            $redirect = add_query_arg('post', 'failed', home_url($_POST['_wp_http_referer']));
        } else {

            $category = array( $_POST['genres'] );

            $post_info = array(
                'post_type' => 'movies',
                'post_status' => 'pending',
                'post_title' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['title'])),
                'post_content' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['overview'])),
                'post_category' => $category,

            );
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_info);

            if($post_id) {
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'ecpt_postedby', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['user_name'])));
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'ecpt_posteremail', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['user_email'])));
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'ecpt_contactemail', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['inquiry_email'])));
                $redirect = add_query_arg('post', 'successfull', home_url($_POST['_wp_http_referer']));
            }
        }
        wp_redirect($redirect); exit;
    }
}
add_action('init', 'post_creation');
```

Categories not save to post.

I want to add new post to categories if it already exist And create new category if it doesn't exist

Comment: any help ??????

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use the default `Post` post type's `Category` taxonomy with your custom post type `movies`.

```
$post_info = array(
  'post_type'     => 'movies', // custom post type here
  'post_status'   => 'pending',
  'post_title'    => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['title'])),
  'post_content'  => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['overview'])),
  'post_category' => $category, // categories are by default only for Post post type
);
```

Have you already added such code to your site, which allows you to use the default `Category` taxonomy with your custom post type? If not, have a look here on how to do it, [tags & categories with custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7138/tags-categories-with-custom-post-type)

If you have registered a custom taxonomy for your `movies` post type, then you should use `tax_input` in your `$post_info` array. Like so,

```
$post_info = array(
  'post_type'     => 'movies',
  'post_status'   => 'pending',
  'post_title'    => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['title'])),
  'post_content'  => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['overview'])),
  'tax_input'     => array(
    'some_custom_taxonomy' => $category
  ),
);
```